# Missing observations when using str_replace_all

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, str-replace

I have a dataset of map data using the following:

```
worldMap_df <- map_data("world") %>%
  rename(Economy = region) %>%
  filter(Economy != "Antarctica") %>%
  mutate(Economy = str_replace_all(Economy,
                                   c("Brunei" = "Brunei Darussalam",
                                     "Macedonia" = "Macedonia, FYR",
                                     "Puerto Rico" = "Puerto Rico US",
                                     "Russia" = "Russian Federation",
                                     "UK" = "United Kingdom",
                                     "USA" = "United States",
                                     "Palestine" = "West Bank and Gaza",
                                     "Saint Lucia" = "St Lucia",
                                     "East Timor" = "Timor-Leste")))
```

There are a number of countries (under `Economy`) that I am trying to use str_replace_all to concatenate. One example is observations for which `Economy` is either "Trinidad" or "Tobago".

I've used the following but this seems to only partially re-label observations:

```
trin_tobago_vector <- c("Trinidad", "Tobago")
worldMap_df$Economy <- str_replace_all(worldMap_df$Economy, trin_tobago_vector, "Trinidad and Tobago")
```

However, certain observations still have *Trinidad and Tobago* under `Economy` whilst others remain *Trinidad* OR *Tobago*. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You supply `str_replace_all` with a pattern that is a vector: `trin_tobago_vector`. It will then iterate over your 'Economy' column and check the first element with "Trinidad", the second element with "Tobago", the third with "Trinidad", and so on. You should do this replacement in two steps instead:

```
worldMap_df$Economy <- str_replace_all(worldMap_df$Economy, "^Trinidad$", "Trinidad and Tobago")
worldMap_df$Economy <- str_replace_all(worldMap_df$Economy, "^Tobago$", "Trinidad and Tobago")
```

or use a named vector:

```
trin_tobago_vector <- c("^Trinidad$" = "Trinidad and Tobago", "^Tobago$" = "Trinidad and Tobago")
worldMap_df$Economy <- str_replace_all(worldMap_df$Economy, trin_tobago_vector)
```

The `^` and `$` inside the pattern vector make sure that only the literal strings `"Trinidad"` and `"Tobago"` are replaced.

Comment: Hi @Basibo1 I tried doing something like this by including `"Trinidad" = "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tobago" = "Trinidad and Tobago"` in the call to `mutate`, originally. Doing this and with either of your solutions I end with "Trinidad and Trinidad and Tobago" for certain observations. Is there anyway to tell R to search ONLY for "Trinidad" OR "Tobago" as unique strings?

Comment: Ah, you're completely right. What happens if you use `str_replace` instead of `str_replace_all` in my second solution? Another solution might be to turn it into a regular expression by writing `"^Trinidad$"` and `"^Tobago$"`, see my edited answer.

Comment: Using `str_replace` throws an error `Error in fix_replacement(replacement) : 
  argument "replacement" is missing, with no default`. Should I use the regular expression inside the original mutate call?

Comment: Fantastic, seems to work perfectly, either within the list inside the original call to mutate or by first defining a vector. Thank you!